# Gradle plugin (tomee-embedded) dependency for TomEE error

Tags: gradle, apache-tomee, tomee-7

**Objective:**

Use gradle to build TomEE project.

**Gradle Script:**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.tomee.gradle:tomee-embedded:7.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.apache.tomee.tomee-embedded'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**Gradle call:**  `gradle tomee-embedded`

Execution failed for task ':tomee-embedded'.

> org.gradle.api.logging.LoggingManager.setLevel(Lorg/gradle/api/logging/LogLevel;)Lorg/gradle/api/logging/LoggingManager;

**Error cause by:**

Caused by:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.gradle.api.logging.LoggingManager.setLevel(Lorg/gradle/api/logging/LogLevel;)Lorg/gradle/api/logging/LoggingManager;

Did I happen to miss to add gradle dependency? Shouldnt gradle know that it has to add its APIs as well? Do i do it manually? I tried adding to classpath all gradle api libraries but with no success. Anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it got fixed in 7.0.2, gradle API changed on that area